# How to recover a screen session?

Tags: shell, socket, gnu-screen

I'm running a screen session and it seems it hung up somehow.

```
0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ screen -ls
There are screens on:
  30418.pts-2.hoster (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screens/S-user.
```

However, when I try to attach with `screen -r`, nothing happens, the shell just hangs somehow. I also tried to reattach to the screen by using the ID and `-d`; and also tried [the *angry* mode with `-DR`](https://serverfault.com/a/564250/116529) but nothing happens.

```
0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ screen -DR 30418
^Ad
^C
exit
```

As you can see, it simply does nothing and the shell is hanging somehow, `^A-d` does not work, `^D`, `^C` or `exit` neither.

How to recover that screen session?

---

*Edit*: ArchLinux, LTS kernel 4.4.12

```
2 ✗ user@hoster ~ $ sudo ls -l /proc/30418/fd
[sudo] password for user: 
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 10 -> /dev/ptmx
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 4 -> 'socket:[32652]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 5 -> /run/utmp
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 6 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 7 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 8 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 28. Jun 11:06 9 -> /dev/ptmx
1 ✗ user@hoster ~ $ sudo cat /proc/30418/stack
[<ffffffff811ef3c4>] poll_schedule_timeout+0x44/0x70
[<ffffffff811efe8f>] do_select+0x72f/0x7f0
[<ffffffff811f0159>] core_sys_select+0x209/0x2f0
[<ffffffff811f02fa>] SyS_select+0xba/0x110
[<ffffffff8158db6e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Can you get a stack trace of your screen process and some info on its open files? Assuming this is on Linux: from another session, find the PID of screen using `ps aux|grep screen` then run `cat /proc/PID/stack` and `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`.

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about how unix works than about systems administration. In other words, the close vote currently on your question is not about actually closing but about moving.

Comment: What process is connected to socket 32652? Maybe this [socket_peers tool](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/unix_sockets_peers) might help.

Comment: Output of `ps -ft pts/2` please. (You may need to run that as root, depending on your distro.)

Comment: Title of the question linked is [Cannot reattach to a screen session after SSH connection was dropped](https://serverfault.com/q/558664)